# "numpy" is not accessed Pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio, numpy, import, interpreter

After importing numpy, I get an error "No module named 'numpy'".

vs code also tell me ""numpy" is not accessed"

> import numpy
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

This isn't because I don't have numpy installed. I've installed and used it in the same directory I'm using at the moment.

I've already tried to install numpy multiple times in an infinite amount of ways, but none resolve the issue.

I've come across solutions that say to select the python interpreter, but none work.

I should add, not all modules have this issue.

What can I do to be able to use numpy in vs code?